# How do I select single items out of an array in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am new to coding and I want to select a single Item out of an array. So far I have built an array of items (pretty similar to what you can see on "Tinder" for example) but If I tab on one of the items all of the others will be filled blue as well. Does any one know how do modify the code so it will work? Thank you in advance.

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct WhatInterestsYouView: View {
    
    let sportsSelectionItems = ["NFL", "CollegeFootball", "soccer", "baseball", "tennis", "Icehockey", "Gym", "running", "climbing"]
    let layout = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]
    @State private var sportsSelectionItemIsSelected:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid (columns: layout, spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(sportsSelectionItems, id: \.self) { selectionItem in
                Text(selectionItem)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        sportsSelectionItemIsSelected.toggle()
                    }
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.all, 5)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(sportsSelectionItemIsSelected ? Color.blue : Color.gray.opacity(0.1)))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WhatInterestsYouView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WhatInterestsYouView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "sportsSelectionItemIsSelected:Bool" is just a flag common in the View and it is not bound to any item in the array. so once it becomes true, it remains true for all the items in array.

Instead, have the selected item of array stored and compare it with items in loop and fill it out with your color. like this,

```
@State private var selectedItem: String?
var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid (columns: layout, spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(sportsSelectionItems, id: \.self) { selectionItem in
            Text(selectionItem)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedItem = selectionItem
                }
                .font(.footnote)
                .padding(.all, 5)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(selectedItem == selectionItem ? Color.blue : Color.gray.opacity(0.1)))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but is there a way to modify it so that you can choose multiple items and every selected item should be able to switch their color independend

Comment: If that is the case, Have a struct with 2 variables and maintain it in array. loop it out and handle it.

i) kindly have two variables (var Name, var Flag) in struct SportSelection. 
then sportsSelectionItems should be of type [SportSelection] assign Predeclared values with Flag as false.
ii) put it in loop and Text(selectionItem).Name and onTapGesture selectionItem.Flag.toggle().
iii) At .fill selectionItem.Flag is suffice to meet your expectation.